# How can I make this html form use internal php instead of an external php file?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am making a simple html form, using the method below to post.

I want all the php in the htm file. (i know you can just rename contact.htm to contact.php but that does not tell me how to change it from external file to internal code and where to put the code)

Any suggestions?

```
Part of the .html form: 

<form method="post" action="forms/contact.php">
   ......
<button type="submit" tabindex="5">Submit Contact Form</button>
</form>
......

.php file:

<?php
$webmaster_email = "me@mail.com";
$thankyou_page = "thanks.html";
$error_page = "errors.html";
$firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'] ;
$lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

$msg = "\r\nFirst Name: " . $firstname . "\r\n\r\nLast Name: " . $lastname . "\r\n\r\nE-mail address: " . $email . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . $message . "\r\n";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    mail( "$webmaster_email", "Message on Contact Form", $msg );
    header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}

else {
    header( "Location: $error_page" );
}
?>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.  Currently the form is posting to `forms/contact.php`.  Is the PHP code you're showing us from that PHP file?  What specifically isn't working as expected?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working now. Thank you so much everyone for the help guys! Here is how I did it:

Line 1 (Must be the very first line):

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>   // I don't know what this is but it made it work!
```

The Rest of the code wherever you want it (together, php right on top):

```
<?php
$webmaster_email = "email@domain.com";
$thankyou_page = "thanks.html";
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$comment = $_REQUEST['comment'] ;
if (empty($name)) { $name='Anonymous';  }
$msg = "\r\nName: " . $name . "\r\n\r\nComment: " . $comment . "\r\n";  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {   // if clicked submit button
    mail( "$webmaster_email", "Comment on domain.com", $msg );
    header( "Location: $thankyou_page" ); }   // takes you to thank you page
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <label><h4>Name</h4>
    <input type="text" name="name" tabindex="1">
    </label>
    <br>
    <font size="3">
    <label><h4>Comment</h4>
    <textarea name="comment" minlength="10" maxlength="650" tabindex="2"> 
    </textarea>
    </label>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" tabindex="3">Submit Comment</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

To include the PHP code directly within your HTML file, you need to save your HTML file with a .php extension and then embed the PHP code within the HTML using the  tags. Here's how you can do it:

Save your HTML file with a .php extension, for example, contact.php.

Modify your HTML form to include the PHP code within it:

```
     <html>

     <head>
        <title>Contact Form</title>
     </head>

     <body>
        <?php
            $webmaster_email = "me@mail.com";
            $thankyou_page = "thanks.html";
            $error_page = "errors.html";
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
                $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
                $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];
                $msg = "\r\nFirst Name: " . $firstname . "\r\n\r\nLast Name: " . $lastname . "\r\n\r\nE-mail address: " . $email . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . $message . "\r\n";
                if (mail($webmaster_email, "Message on Contact Form", $msg)) {
                    header("Location: $thankyou_page");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    header("Location: $error_page");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            ?>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required>
            .....
            <button type="submit" tabindex="5">Submit Contact Form</button>
        </form>
     </body>

     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have everything in one file.

You would first need to rename your file to a .php file. Then, if the `action` attribute is empty on the form element the form will submit to the same page (eg: reloads the page with the form data).

Then you can have all of the PHP code in the top and just have a check if there is POST data being submitted.

```
<?php
if( $_POST ){
   $webmaster_email = "me@mail.com";
   $thankyou_page = "thanks.html";
   $error_page = "errors.html";
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'] ;
   $lastname = $_POST['lastname'] ;
   $email = $_POST['email'] ;
   $message = $_POST['message'] ;

   $msg = "\r\nFirst Name: " . $firstname . "\r\n\r\nLast Name: " . $lastname . "\r\n\r\nE-mail address: " . $email . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . $message . "\r\n";

   mail( "$webmaster_email", "Message on Contact Form", $msg );
   header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}?>

<form method="post" action="">
   ......
<button type="submit" tabindex="5">Submit Contact Form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks guys, but none of that works.
I know it is possible but I just can't get it right.
Where exactly would I put the codes? It was so easy with an external php file.
the php block should go right after the form code?

Comment: adding <?php ob_start(); ?> at the top makes the form work BUT it does not change pages after. I have tried moving that code to different positions, above <!DOCTYPE> below <html lang="en"> in the <head> at the start of the <body> Nothing works properly. How can I get it to go to a different page after? Shouldn't it work if it sends the email properly?

Comment: Thanks guys!! i kept changing the place of things. It works with the <?php ob_start(); ?> on the 1st line even above <!DOCTYPE HTML> and the rest of the code I put directly above the html form with the action=""  . . .  I was wondering if the <!DOCTYPE HTML> and <html lang="en"> are supposed to be a php file? it works but is it proper?

Answer (score 0):

The entire content in a single file as contact.php. code as follows...

```
<form method="post"><!--remove action as it comes back here(this page) only-->
......
<button type="submit" tabindex="5">Submit Contact Form</button>
</form>
......

<!--php part....-->

<?php
$webmaster_email = "me@mail.com";
$thankyou_page = "thanks.html";
$error_page = "errors.html";
$firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'] ;
$lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

$msg = "\r\nFirst Name: " . $firstname . "\r\n\r\nLast Name: " . $lastname . "\r\n\r\nE-mail address: " . $email . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . $message . "\r\n";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    mail( "$webmaster_email", "Message on Contact Form", $msg );
    header( "Location: $thankyou_page");
}

else {
    header( "Location: $error_page" );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, that works BUT the refresh page isn't working though, I want it to go to the error or welcome page like it did when the php was external.

Comment: okay, it works when i try to go to a fake url, the redirect takes me to the error page. BUT when the form is successfully filled out and submitted, the page refreshes without redirecting like it used to. Something is wrong with that code now something needs to be different.... anyone help?

Comment: just add `<?php ob_start(); ?>` at the top of the page. and put `exit();` after `header( "Location: $thankyou_page");`  hope this will solve your problem.